# Vb6 Moving Platforms in a 2d side scroller

Tags: vb6, 2d, platform

Ok so I have developed a 2d side scroller (platformer) and it is pretty darn efficient IMO, uses 1 timer, and im trying to make moving platforms possible. Here is what i tried and am debugging with

```
 Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
'moving platforms
For f = 0 To Platform.Count - 1
    If Platform(f).Tag = "moving" Then
        For j = 0 To Platform.Count - 1
            If Collision(Platform(f), Platform(j)) And j <> f Then
                Speed(f) = Speed(f) * -1
            End If
        Next j
        Platform(f).Left = Platform(f).Left + Speed(f)
    End If
Next f
```

Basically, here iswhat the code does:
For all the platforms, it checks which platform has the tag "moving", if it does have that tag, move it, but before moving it, see if it needs to have a direction change, so it loops through all the platforms again to see if it needs to change again, and should do so if it needs to, but in this code it doesnt work :(

What could be the problem? The intial value of all the Speeds is 1, and I have scalemode to pixel, thats why its so small. Any help is appreciated

Collision function:

```
Public Function Collision(Shape1 As Control, Shape2 As Control) As Boolean
If (Shape1.Left + Shape1.Width) > Shape2.Left _
And Shape1.Left < (Shape2.Left + Shape2.Width) _
And (Shape1.Top + Shape1.Height) > Shape2.Top _
And (Shape1.Top + Shape1.Height) < Shape2.Top + Shape2.Height Then
    Collision = True
Else
    Collision = False
End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alrighty, the problem has been solved. Observe this Collision function:

```
Public Function Collision(Shape1 As Control, Shape2 As Control) As Boolean
    If (Shape1.Left + Shape1.Width) > Shape2.Left _
    And Shape1.Left < (Shape2.Left + Shape2.Width) _
    And (Shape1.Top + Shape1.Height) > Shape2.Top _
    And (Shape1.Top + Shape1.Height) < Shape2.Top + Shape2.Height Then
        Collision = True
    Else
        Collision = False
    End If
End Function
```

Notice the problem? The 2 platforms I am testing for collision for, in this case, are at the same **height**. Think about it, if you see in that collision function, the last condition:

```
(Shape1.Top + Shape1.Height) < Shape2.Top + Shape2.Height
```

Since Shape1 has the same Top as Shape2, this condition is false because I sued the less than sign, and not the less than or EQUAL to sign. To make sure there is no problem, I replaced all my signs with or equal to ones.

```
Public Function Collision(Shape1 As Control, Shape2 As Control) As Boolean
    If (Shape1.Left + Shape1.Width) >= Shape2.Left _
    And Shape1.Left <= (Shape2.Left + Shape2.Width) _
    And (Shape1.Top + Shape1.Height) >= Shape2.Top _
    And (Shape1.Top + Shape1.Height) <= Shape2.Top + Shape2.Height Then
        Collision = True
    Else
        Collision = False
    End If
```

End Function

Would you look at that! A moving platform that bounces between the platforms beside it. Beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of optimizations for you to consider:

1) Unlike other languages, vb evaluates all expressions in a statement. In other words:

If FunctionA = true and FunctionB = true then DoSomething

Is always going to run FunctionB even if FunctionA was false.  In your timer, you could check that j is not equal to f in an if statement before your Collision check to avoid wasting time checking for that collision when you already know you're going to ignore it.

2) If I loop from 1 to 3 in an outer and inner loop I end up comparing:

```
    1 - 1
    1 - 2
    1 - 3
    2 - 1
    2 - 2
    2 - 3
    3 - 1
    3 - 2
    3 - 3
```

If I was smart I would make my inner loop start one higher than my outer loop.  Then I only end up with the following:

```
    1 - 2
    1 - 3
    2 - 3
```

That's a lot less loops and that's only on 3 numbers.

Try replacing your for loop line with this:
For j = f + 1 To Platform.Count - 1

And if you do that you have the added benefit of not needing to check for j <> f too.

Answer (score 0):

This code looks fine.
i think the error happens in your collision code since that code sets your speed.

try

Speed(f) = -Speed(f);

And also do you actually hit the speed change?
What's the value of speed after a collision?

Comment: I added the collision function, what do you mean by speed to 0? I forgot to mention that the platform moves, but never changes direction upon collision with the other platform.

Comment: Before it never hit this because of my answer above. Also * -1 reverses a number, and yours actually looks more cleaner so I will use your reversing for future, thanks for the help :)

Comment: No prob. You're doing what i am supposed to be doing :P making games.